# What is original definition of WNS (worst negative slack) and WHS?

Tags: timing-analysis

I am new to STA, and a bit confused by the terms such as WNS/WHS etc. Searching the web, it seems there are discussions on xilinx wiki about those terms (some called WNS is a misnomer, e.g., [here](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006iHoJ8SAK/total-negative-slack-vs-worst-negative-slack?language=en_US)).

It seems that the terms WNS/WHS, etc., are only applicable to Vivado, but I am not sure. For other STA tools (e.g., from Altera/Intel, or Synopsys, etc), are they using the same terminology such as WNS/WHS? If yes, where can I find the origin of the definition of the terms?

Comment: synopsys uses wns.

Answer (score 3):

The term "slack" may be unique to Xilinx, but I think I've seen it used elsewhere. In any case, the definition of "slack" is the amount of margin between your actual circuit delay and the requirements of that circuit, as defined by the clock period, etc. More slack means that you have greater timing margins, and "negative slack" means that you're violating the requirement.

Xilinx lists the "worst negative slack" first in their reports on the assumption that these are the areas you're going to want to focus on first in the process of optimizing your design for timing.